# Issue in left join using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have this query here

```
$rs = mysql_query("select Username.users,phone.users,user_id.coupon,points.coupon,time.coupon from users LEFT JOIN coupon on Username.users = coupon.user_id where coupon.user_id like '%$search%' or coupon.time like '%$search%' order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows"); 

Where 

$sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? strval($_POST['sort']) : 'time';
```

Am i doing any error here?
I don't get any result, 
please help me with this.

Thanks..

Comment: what error messages do you get? How does the actual query look like? does this match with the structure of your tables?

Comment: you have switched all table and field names, it should be `table.field` not `field.table`

Comment: Use that query directly in Mysql and replace the values.Report back the error.

Comment: user_id.coupon and coupon.user_id ? what is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `columnname.tablename` instead of `tablename.columnname`. So instead of `Username.users` use `users.Username` and all respective.

```
select users.Username  --<-- here 
      ,users.phone ,coupon.user_id. ,coupon.points ,coupon.time
  from users LEFT JOIN coupon 
    on users.Username = coupon.user_id  --<-- also here
 where ...
```

Also, you can use *alias* to reduce your query length and time of writing query and for more simplicity like this:

```
select u.Username  --<-- here 
      ,u.phone ,c.user_id. ,c.points ,c.time
  from users u LEFT JOIN coupon c
    on u.Username = c.user_id  --<-- also here
 where ...
```

Comment: am i correct? $rs = mysql_query("select users.Username,users.phone,coupon.user_id,coupon.points,coupon.time from users LEFT JOIN coupon on users.Username = user_id.coupon where coupon.user_id like '%$search%' or coupon.time like '%$search%' order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows");

Comment: @al_alb - Still one mistake in `ON` it should be: `on users.Username = coupon.user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the query the following way which may help:

```
$rs = mysql_query("select users.Username,users.phone,coupon.user_id,coupon.points,coupon.time from users LEFT JOIN coupon on users.Username = coupon.user_id 
where coupon.user_id like '%$search%' or coupon.time like '%$search%' order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows");
```

Just verify that `users.Username` is in fact the correct id to join on the coupon table. Shouldn't it be `users.user_id`? In which case it will be

```
$rs = mysql_query("select users.Username,users.phone,coupon.user_id,coupon.points,coupon.time from users LEFT JOIN coupon on users.user_id = coupon.user_id 
where coupon.user_id like '%$search%' or coupon.time like '%$search%' order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows");
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly ell, thank you, im accepting in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

more appropriate method,

as time is a type in Sql

```
select users.`Username`, users.`phone`, coupon.`user_id`, coupon.`points`,coupon.`time` from users 
LEFT JOIN coupon 
on users.`Username` = coupon.`user_id` 
where coupon.`user_id` like '%$search%' or coupon.`time` like '%$search%'
```